# Using SHA256 + SHA512 hash for password?

Tags: vb.net, security, passwords

I'm creating a method that I will use to hash password to store in a database. I would like to seek advice if my methods in hashing is sufficient or overkill for the task.

```
    Dim result As Byte()
    Dim mixer As String

    Try
        Dim sha As New SHA512CryptoServiceProvider

        mixer = txt_salt.Text.ToUpper + txt_pass.Text.Trim
        result = sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mixer))

        txt_sha.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(result)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It is insufficient.**

1. No salt:

   - vulnerable to [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) (if hashes are leaked)
   - solution: use *random* [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) in *large* domain
2. Hashes are too fast:

   - vulnerable to brute-force (if hashes are leaked)
   - most hashing algorithms are designed to be *fast*
   - solution: [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) or multiple (many!!!) rounds
3. No HMAC:

   - does not have additional "server secret" (stored outside db!)
   - solution: [hmac-sha1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), etc.
4. Not part of a well-tested library/framework for authentication:

   - this is a "roll your own" implementation
   - solution: don't reinvent a wheel, unless it's one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweel) or [these](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jYcX_D09ig) :)

As far as "bits" go, SHA1 is perfectly fine with 160 (but it is not fine [by itself] for other reasons). Doing both SHA256+SH512 just complicates the matter for *zero gain*. (Actually, it is a very slight net loss due to the extra storage requirements.)

I suggest using an existing library/system, unless this is an academic project :)

Happy coding.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean on #3?

Comment: @Mr. A #4 now ;-) Security is not something to be taken lightly. Use a project/library *designed* to handle this problem -- that is, there is no other purpose of said library. This library should have a solid design (covering the other points mentioned), and should be well tested and there should be no known security vulnerabilities. Looking at bug reports (and time to resolution) often indicates the quality of a library for this purpose.

Comment: I'm a bit new in the security aspect of programming, can you recommend an existing library in the .net framework that I can use?

Comment: @Mr A. Not for .NET, unfortunately :( I do nothing remotely secure in it.

Comment: Agree except for point 3. An HMAC is not a part of standard practice for securely storing passwords, because only contrived threat models have an attacker gaining access to your database but not your source code.

Comment: @NickJohnson The idea is that the database and "server secret" are separate -- say the DB is compromised with a SQL injection attack (yeah, yeah) -- while the secret is still safe (say encrypted in `web.config` through the Windows Data Protection API). And, honestly, if someone gets in to *that* level [full remote execution or "root" context - *not* just "source code"], then you're fsked anyway. However, not really a point to *not* use a server-secret IMOHO. But then, I really recommend using an *existing provider* for authentication management :)