# VB.net Login Control encrypting password

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the asp.net login control to register and log in/out users. I have seen a few examples in C# but I am using VB.
The main problem I have in trying to figure this out is that the Login control in VB does not show me how it is doing anything.
This is what my VB for register user looks like.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl = Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl")
End Sub



Protected Sub RegisterUser_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles RegisterUser.CreatedUser
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, False)

    Dim continueUrl As String = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(continueUrl) Then
        continueUrl = "~/"
    End If

    Response.Redirect(continueUrl)
End Sub


End Class
```

Anyone know how to send the password as a hash?

I have also heard of using SSL.
Anyone know of any references for doing this or how to implement code into this VB file?

Answer (score -1):

You can use SHA, or whichever encryption you like to encrypt and save that.

[SHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337738/using-sha256-sha512-hash-for-password)

Comment: Never, never store the result of `GetHashCode` in the database.  The result of `GetHashCode` is not gauranteed to never change and has in fact already changed between versions of the CLR.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: Okay, thank you for your advise. Do you know a resource to help me edit the Logincontrol VB file?